# Python/CSV - Method to create a CSV file with argument as file name

Tags: python, csv

I want to create empty csv files (that will later be used for something else) with its name based on the method's arguments. It will be something like this:

```
def create_empty_csvs(*string_csv_names):
    for i in stringcsv_names:
        --> create empty csv file with argument name
```

So, if I call this:

```
create_empty_csvs('John','Mark','Daniel')
```

It would return me three different empty csv files, named 'John.csv', 'Mark.csv' and 'Daniel.csv'.

Any idea how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create_empty_csvs(*stringcsv_names):
    for i in stringcsv_names:
        with open(i + '.csv', 'w') as f:
            pass
```

for more information, see python doc for [open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).